# Generating schema for a JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema

I am looking for a Free JS lib/tool for generating JSON schema for a JSON data.
So that at end i have a function which accepts two parameters jsonData and defaultRequired.

```
jsonData (js object) => JSON data of which JSON schema to be found
defaultRequired (boolean) => boolean field if we need to make all the properties 'must required'
```

function should return a JS object which is the JSON schema of the jsonData.

I have gone though this http://www.jsonschema.net/
As the tool is online. We have to manually insert data and get the JSON schema. But i did not found any way to link it in my application and getting the above function and work the same in my own application.

I also gone through https://github.com/perenecabuto/json_schema_generator
But this one is written in python so probably can not use in my application.

Can anyone suggest a good JS lib for the same.

Comment: Just to check - you're looking for a way to *generate* schemas on-the-fly, not validate them?

Comment: yes i only want to generate schemas,... and NOT to validate them

Answer (score 0):

The following JS function generates the JSON schema as an object. But it does not check if the properties are mandatory or not.

```
function getSchema(id, obj) {

  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    var  retObj = getSchema(id, obj[0]);
    delete retObj.title;
    return {
      'title': id,
      'type': 'array',
      'items': retObj
    };
  } else if (typeof obj === 'object') {
    var retObj = {
      'title': id,
      'type': 'object'
    };
    retObj.properties = {};
    for (var prop in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        retObj.properties[prop] = getSchema(prop, obj[prop]);
        delete retObj.properties[prop].title;
      }
    }

    return retObj;
  } else {
    return {
      'title': id,
      'type': typeof obj
    };
  }
}
```

You can invoke the function as follows

```
k = {
  a: 1,
  b: '2',
  c: [3]
}


console.log(getSchema('Sample Object', k));
```